# location on mapView

Tags: ios, mkmapview

i have a map and i want to set the user location ( blue dot ) when i open it.i tried lot of things and didn't work.please help me

```
MKCoordinateRegion region;
region.center.latitude=BG_LATITUDE;
region.center.longitude=BG_LONGITUDE;
region.span.latitudeDelta=SPAN_VALUE;
region.span.longitudeDelta=SPAN_VALUE;
[self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];



NSMutableArray *annotations =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
//coordinate (for the annotation)
CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
mapAnnotation *ann;




location.latitude=MaB_LATITUDE;
location.longitude=MaB_LONGITUDE;
//annotation
ann = [[mapAnnotation alloc]init];
[ann setCoordinate:location];
ann.title=@"Main Branch";
[annotations addObject:ann];
```

Answer (score 4):

you dont need to write so much lines of code to show the blue dot , MKMapView itself contains a property called "showUserLocation" which has to be set as true in order to show blue dot on to the Map .

```
self.mapView.showsUserLocation = TRUE;
```

It also automatically tracks the Device's Location . Hope it will help you .

Comment: i did that before asking but it didn't work.any other ideas ??

Answer (score 1):

Use this if you want show user location on map

```
self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
```

Comment: not work.and there is a pin location named current location in America and i am in Iraq !!!

Comment: @EngMustafaW : it is showing you the location of America because you might be testing the app on simulator and simulator default pick up the location of America , in order to get the correct location use iOS Device or add .gpx file to your project , so that you can test the same on simulaotr.

Comment: how can i add .gpx file ?